# Comparing Column Contents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I am trying to compare the contents of two columns named C1 and C2, each of them having some 250 values. I want to create another field, named C3, with TRUE if a value from C1 is found anywhere in C2, or FALSE, if not.

I found [something](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165316/how-to-compare-the-string-in-one-column-to-some-others) which is very close, but it works only for the same entry in each column.

I am using QGIS 2.12 and I am curious if there is any expression that I can use.

*edit*: C1 is called NAME, C2 is DIST_ORIG

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Just a thought: duplicate the layer, and join them on `NAME=DIST_ORIG` might give you the rows that can be set to TRUE.

Comment: In what format is the data?  SQL expressions only pertain to database sources.

Comment: @AndreJ your advice proved to be the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way in QGIS:

1. duplicate the layer
2. join them on `NAME=DIST_ORIG`

The remaining rows are those that can be set to TRUE.

You might stumble on typos, trailing blanks etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an expression which will do the trick - just substitute your actual layer name below:

```
case when
attribute(get_feature('YOUR_LAYER_NAME','DIST_ORIG',"NAME"),'DIST_ORIG') then true
else false
end
```

To break this down:

```
get_feature('YOUR_LAYER_NAME','DIST_ORIG',"NAME")
```

this part will fetch the first feature from your layer where the DIST_ORIG value matches "NAME" (eg, the value in the "NAME" column for the current feature). If there's no matching features found, nothing will be returned by this function.

We then need to do a little trick to convert this to a condition we can use in the `CASE WHEN / ELSE / END` statement. So I've wrapped the `get_feature` call in a `attribute` function, which will return the value in the specified field from the feature returned by `get_feature`. So this will either be a value from "DIST_ORIG" if a feature was found, or `NULL` if no feature was found.

Then the `CASE WHEN / ELSE / END` is just used to directly convert the result to a true/false value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a custom function in the field calculator.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def isInColumn(value1, feature, parent):
    return 0 if value1 == None else 1
```

In the field calculator you use the function with the result of the getFeature()
expression like this:

```
 isInColumn(getFeature( 'YOUR_LAYER_NAME', 'COLUMN_TO_SEARCH_IN', "VALUE_FROM_SEARCH_COLUMN"))
```

If the function `isInColumn()` gets a valid Feature, it Returns '1' (true) otherwise '0' (false). So you can update the third column.

Comment: Note that I've actually fixed this in QGIS itself now - so you can use the results of get_feature() or geometry() directly as a boolean criteria. This will be available from versions >=2.14.