# Compare two columns using Graphical Modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have a layer with several columns. One of them is called 'cod' and the other is called 'cod_2'. 'cod_2' is null, except for one row. I want to know if the numerical value of 'cod_2' is present in any row of 'cod'. I'll give you an example.

```
Cod Cod_2
1     NULL
1     NULL
18    NULL
3     NULL
42    18
42    NULL
7     NULL
```

18 is present in both columns, but not in the same row. So, I can't use

```
if("col"="col_2",1,0)
```

because it will return 0.

I've tried this solution ([Comparing Column Contents in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169564/comparing-column-contents-in-qgis/169662#169662)) but it's not working because I'm working with Graphical Moduler, thus I can't call the layer name. I've tried to use @layer_name but it didn't worked either.

Comment: As pointet out in  the solution you linked to, you can duplicate your layer, then joining the duplicated layer using the columns "col" and "col_2". If there are results in the joined layer you have values in col_2 which are also present in col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for an **Aggregate** function.

Use `array_agg` to combine all the values in "cod_2" into an array.

```
array_agg("cod_2")
```

Now that the "cod_2" values are in an array, we can use the **Array** functions. In this case, use `array_find(array,value)` to find the "cod" value in the array.

```
array_find(array_agg("cod_2"),"cod")
```

- If the "cod" value is in the array, the output will be a non-negative integer.
- If the current "cod" value is not in the array, the output will be `-1`.

Now we can write a true/false expression to test whether the current "cod" number is in the "cod_2" column.

```
array_find(array_agg("cod_2"),"cod")>-1
```

- If the current "cod" value **is** in the "cod_2" column, the output will be **1**.
- If the current "cod" value **is not** in the "cod_2" column, the output will be **0**.

If you want outputs other than 1 for true and 0 for false, use an if statement.

```
if(array_find(array_agg("cod_2"),"cod")>-1, result when true, result when false)
```